# is(":hover") only working within a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/cot33dxa/

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#one").is(":hover")) {
    $("#one").css("background-color", "red");
  } else {
    $("#one").css("background-color", "");
  }
}, 0);

if ($("#two").is(":hover")) {
  $("#two").css("background-color", "blue");
} else {
  $("#two").css("background-color", "");
}
```

```css
#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Why is it that for div one, the hover check works just fine, whereas it doesn't in div two?

I have the same issue when using `if ($('#element:hover').length != 0)` (taken from [ivo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382705/2472351)).

JS fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/q8dfLc6s/

In a more general sense, I am looking for the simplest, most reliable way to know if the mouse is over a div in JQuery 1.11.0. As it stands, I can't even get the boolean check to work at all aside from this SetInterval oddity.

Comment: Why are you using a setInterval instead of either the dom mouseover/enter/out/leave event ([jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)), or the :hover css pseudo class(if you are only needing this for doing styling)?

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Because it was used here in a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/8981521/2472351 I was trying to reverse engineer his solution and didn't understand why the boolean check would stop working once the setInterval function was factored out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your fiddle is that your second check is outside of your interval function. Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($("#one").is(":hover")) {
        $("#one").css("background-color","red");
    }
    else {
        $("#one").css("background-color","");
    }

    if($("#two").is(":hover")) {
        $("#two").css("background-color","blue");
    }
    else {
        $("#two").css("background-color","");
    }

},0);
```

Comment: But why do I need to use the interval function at all? If, for example, I use this boolean logic inside of a mouseclick event, I get the same problem.

Comment: @Amalgam54 Inside a click event, you must be over the thing you're clicking on, so you can't be hovering over something else.

Comment: Because the boolean logic only executes once. You need to use a mouseleave event like you were using in your other question.

Comment: Oh it's not working in your event function? Can you post the code of your mouseclick event handler?

Comment: @Tatermelon try https://jsfiddle.net/w953arn8/ , it only seems to work if you repeatedly move the mouse in and out of the div very quickly

Comment: In that fiddle, the box turns red and stays red for me after I hover out of it the first time. Are you experiencing a different behavior?

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and got the same behavior as you. Seems to be an issue with Firefox (my version is 37.0.2).

Comment: Oh that's strange. Firefox seems to trigger mouseleave slightly before hover is removed. Instead of an interval, you can slightly delay the check by ~50ms using setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

The scond one doesn't work because it's not inside the interval timer and that code only runs on page load therefore

Change to

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#one").is(":hover")) {
        $("#one").css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $("#one").css("background-color", "");
    }


    if ($("#two").is(":hover")) {
        $("#two").css("background-color", "blue");
    } else {
        $("#two").css("background-color", "");
    }

}, 0);
```

I have no idea why you need this and don't just use hover events or hover css

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cot33dxa/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Good question! By putting your code in a setInterval you are essentially mirroring what the browser is doing in the background in the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

This behavior should generally be avoided and instead replaced by an actual event.

in jQuery this would look like:

```
$('#element').on( 'hover', function (this, event) {
    $element = this;
    /*handle event*/
});
```

More here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Edit: The code you are running would be best done in CSS using the `:hover` selector as such:

```
#element {
    background-color: blue
}

#element:hover {
    background-color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving your code inside `setInterval`:
the reason why your second example 'doesnt work', is the fact that it will execute only once the page has loaded. `setInterval` on the other hand, executes every ~0s which 'works'.

However to achieve what you're trying to do, consider to use `.hover()` as it is listening for the actual event of moving the cursor in or out of the selector and will not execute your `else` block all of the time:

```
$(function() {
    $("#two").hover(function() {
        $("#two").css("background-color","blue");
    }, function() {
        $("#two").css("background-color","");
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cot33dxa/3/)